# Why doesn't java File#list() work on Windows Junction points?

Tags: java, windows

*I'm on Windows 8.*
The Javadoc for `File#list()` claims it "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."

Now, take the example of the "directory" (actually a NTFS junction) "Application Data" (found in the C:\Users\[Username] directory).

Calling `File#isDirectory()` on "Application Data" returns `true`. However, calling `File#list()` on "Application Data" returns null, every time... so it's not an I/O error.

Basically, this makes `File#isDirectory()` a useless call, and forces you to check `File#list() != null` if you want to be sure that the `File` is indeed a directory.

Unless I'm wrong, there's no other way to check "for sure" whether a file is actually a directory? `File#list()` is a very expensive method call if you're doing it on every folder on the filesystem.

**Here is a Java file that exemplifies the issue:** http://pastebin.com/ieH0xTek
It will only work on Windows.

Comment: can you show your code? When there is some problem, it's almost always with your code, and not with the method defined in JDK.

Comment: Can someone (beside OP) confirm this problem because I am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: Note I'm talking about "Application Data", not "AppData"

Comment: @RohitJain I've added a test Java class you can run to test it youself.

Comment: Your test gives me `Is Directory: true, Is File: false, List: [Ljava.lang.String;@c2ea3f` so I guess it works as it should. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I get `Is Directory: true, Is File: false, List: null`. I'm on Windows 8?

Comment: Can't reproduce on my machine. Working fine

Comment: I have a large number of "directories" on my system which are returning `null` when I try a `File#list()`. "C:\Users\Default User", "C:\Users\UpdatusUser", "C:\Users\Username\Application Data", "C:\Users\Username\Cookies", "C:\Users\Username\Local Settings", "C:\Users\Username\My Documents"... the list goes on. I'm on Windows 8 and 1.7.0_09.

Comment: What about a more recent java? Update 9 is quite old these days.

Comment: Win-7/JDK-1.6.0_29 and JDK+JRE-1.7.0 - unable to reproduce. Do anyone else (besides OP) have Win8 and was able to reproduce?

Comment: @IanRoberts The issue persists on Windows 8, JDK 1.7.0_40

Comment: Just for the fun I've checked Java sources and the `list` method is pretty simple. If there is any error during the system calls it should be visible with Process Monitor - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx. I still don't believe there is a bug in JRE, but there might be going something strange with file privileges or something like that.

Comment: @PavelHoral you were right about the file privileges. Process Monitor is reporting SUCCESS for "Read Attributes", but ACCESS DENIED for "List Directory". This happens even if I use an Administrator Command Prompt to run my test java class. This just kinda leaves me wondering why... I've never messed with the permissions of these files.

Comment: Ok... I was able to reproduce with Win7. The problem with your example is that it is not pointing to symlink on pre-W8. However it's strange as I did try it on my own junction previously and it worked. So there is something strange going on with the system junctions.

Comment: Just tested that **I was not able to open the symlink folder even in windows file explorer** (access denied)! So it is not a Java specific thing. These system folders are somehow different from other symlinks you can create. That is how far I can get (i.e. Java question stops, Windows question starts :)).

Comment: Aren'T you able to list your own `Application Data`? Please add `System.out.println("read: " + applicationData.canRead()); System.out.println("write: " + applicationData.canWrite()); System.out.println("exec: " + applicationData.canExecute());` to your test and see what is printed, as I see you are trying to list that directory for any user, you might then not have sufficient access to their respective directories.

Comment: @A4L Those method calls are useless on Windows, they all return true unless a File/Folder has "Set Read-Only". Here is the output from 'icacls "Application Data"': http://pastebin.com/f94tmbA8

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756982.aspx

Comment: Hmm... @PavelHoral if you want to post that as an answer and quote the  part where it talks about file attributes and permissions, I'll accept it. That's about as good of an answer as I can hope for, seems Windows just has odd "system junctions" and I'm going to need to account for them.

Comment: @kryo done... added reference to NIO.2 API as it should be possible to resolve the junction target with it. However I didn't try it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden system junctions (such as `Local Settings` or `Application Data`) [are special](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756982.aspx):

> These junction points have file attributes of
>   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM, and the access
>   control lists (ACLs) must be set to "“Everyone Deny Read".
>   Applications must have permissions in order to call out and traverse a
>   specific path. However, enumerating the contents of these junction
>   points is not possible.

This means that they can not be traversed in a standard manner (due to the security settings). Unfortunately there is no way to work with these junctions through the old [Java File API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

With Java 7's [NIO.2 file system API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html) it should be possible to detect these links and probably resolve their target path.

Comment: @LawrenceDol Please check the comments to the original post. `File.list` worked with manually created junction. So the problem lies in these special system junctions. Even watched system calls (as seen by Process Monitor) seems to confirm that.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. My program was not showing folders with the hidden attribute, and mount-point junctions report hidden since Java 7, due to it using the target attribute (which for a mount-point is always hidden unless you also map the drive to a letter, which is, in turn, rare to do for a mounted drive).